# Warehouse Stocking Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

Had been looking for an answer for the following question. But am getting confused and the negative values are distorting any equations which I deem fit.

Say we are running a Walmart Like Store.
The idea is to promote high margin products which make more money, so we make more.

The problem is as follows:

- Say there are different types of chocolates available in store, their buy price, Sell Price and cost incurred for shelfing, blocking capital + Expired return policy.
- If expired Cost is +ve => Distributor pays some cost for loss. If negative, its on shop.

[Warehouse Stocking Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgzyU.png)

Considering advertising into picture, we will promote the ones which are more beneficial to the business.

- The solution needed should provide the order, in which, which chocolates produce more profit:
- Stock high margin products (High SellCost-BuyCost) and which move faster. Faster movement = Less blocked capital per day.
- But, the Loss should be minimal, if product is expired on shelf. (Expired Cost)
- Considering how fast different chocolates Move

Any suggestions on how to get the desired result? Comments and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: "If negative, its on shop." What does that mean?

Comment: I mean, if the value is negative, which means, we lost some principal invested + advertisement cost + interest on the amount blocked to procure. Say the store bought a chocolate for 5$, and it expired without selling. Now the distributor refunded only 3$. The item was on shelf for say 5 months blocking 5$ for 5 months and interest on 5$. say all this adds up to -2.5